# Getting only once permission for sdcard window on Lollipop and above version

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, delete-file, android-sdcard

Hello I am deleting some items from SD card. And in lollipop first time i ask for permission and user grant permission, but now i don't want to ask every time for permission. Its very irritating and many of guys they afraid from this behavior. How can i save my permission i.e. next time i don't need to pass that Intent again and again

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
```

Thank you

Comment: check this answer it will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725699/issues-in-writing-files-to-sd-card-in-android-api-23marshmallow/37725902#37725902

Answer (score 1):

I give you some code to example. Remember that u need check permission on Android 6.0. OnRequestPermission is method that when u have permission will be do code in grantResult, if not u can ask for permission or saying message that user not give a permission. And this method save status for permission

```
@TargetApi(23)
public void checkStoragePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (settingsDrawerFragment != null) {
            settingsDrawerFragment.onPermissionGranted();
        }
        return;
    }
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager
            .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_CODE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return;
    }
    if (settingsDrawerFragment != null) {
        settingsDrawerFragment.onPermissionGranted();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]
        grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_AUDIO_RECORD:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startBrowseActivity();
            } else {
                Utils.showToast(this, getString(R.string.audio_permission_denied));
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (settingsDrawerFragment != null) {
                    settingsDrawerFragment.onPermissionGranted();
                }
            } else {
                if (settingsDrawerFragment != null) {
                    closeSettingsDrawer();
                }
                Utils.showToast(this, getString(R.string.storage_permission_denied));
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: have u know about this Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE); i want this permission to avoid

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop

also if u have onrequestPermissionsResult method- this save ur permission on application

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
                   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
                      builder.dismiss();

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to persist permission

```
 getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Also once you persist permission save the uri in a sharedPreference so that you can delete files later without confirmation.

Comment: i save that uri  in sharedPreference but after phone restart again this prob occur

Comment: are you sure that you are using the above code to persist permission

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
                   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
                      builder.dismiss();

Comment: in onactivity result where you get the uri

Comment: and in onresult and get this      treeUri = data.getData(); and this uri i save for next deletion

Comment: onActivityResult get this treeUri = data.getData();

Comment: localUri2 = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(treeUri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri));

Comment: arrayOfString = MediaWrapper.get(mediaCount).getFilePath().split("/");
        localObject = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(MediaContentActivity.this, localUri2);
        int x = arrayOfString.length;

Comment: for (int jj = 0; jj < x; jj++)
        {
         DocumentFile localDocumentFile = null;
         try{
          localDocumentFile = ((DocumentFile)localObject).findFile(arrayOfString[jj]);
          if (localDocumentFile != null) {
           localObject = localDocumentFile;
          }
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
 
         finally{
          localDocumentFile = null;
         }
        }

Comment: if ((((DocumentFile)localObject).isFile()) && (((DocumentFile)localObject).canWrite())) {
         boolean isFileDelete = ((DocumentFile)localObject).delete();}

Comment: and i found android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS error here from last URI

Comment: r u there i write all my lines above?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch your intent by adding falgs.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how is this different from my answer

Comment: what is do next sohail like where i added this code in my existing code please take a view on my code which a write in comments with other user

Comment: i think you cant delete files using this `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` intent.